# Do I have to have the content.beginPath() and content.closePath()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Does the beginPath and the closePath have to be included for this line to draw or for all of the graphics. I have the new HTML 5 Canvas book but this I was not completely certain of. I commented out the two lines and the line still displayed. What is the significance of these two lines.

**Question: What does the beginPath() and closePath() do?**

Code:

```
context.lineJoin='round';
context.lineCap='butt';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 100);
context.lineTo(35, 100);
context.lineTo(35,125);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, `beginPath` and `closePath` are not necessary.

A canvas context has a current path. You can add instructions to that path with methods such as `moveTo` and `lineTo`, among others. When you're done constructing the path, you can use methods such as `stroke` and `fill`, which draw on the canvas using the current path.

`closePath` is just another instruction you can add. You may not notice its effect when using `fill`, but when using `stroke`, it will (essentially) do a line back to the starting position, ‘closing’ the path. Compare and contrast:

[image: two lines]
[image: a triangle]

```
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(90, 10);    ctx.lineTo(90, 10);
ctx.lineTo(90, 90);    ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
                       ctx.closePath();   
ctx.stroke();          ctx.stroke();
```

`beginPath`, on the other hand, discards the previous path and lets you start a new one. Without it, you'd be appending more and more to the previous path, which may be undesirable. Compare and contrast:

[image: a double-red-blue stroked line and a blue line]
[image: a red line and a blue line]

```
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);           ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(90, 10);           ctx.lineTo(90, 10);
ctx.lineWidth = 4;            ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke();                 ctx.stroke();
                              ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10, 20);           ctx.moveTo(10, 20);
ctx.lineTo(90, 20);           ctx.lineTo(90, 20);
ctx.lineWidth = 2;            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";     ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.stroke();                 ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Are these paths saved in the canvas so you can recall them from an index type situation. In the example you have above you do not have the beginPath() endPath() so these are just appended to the old canvas.

Comment: @user3376708: There is only one path saved at a time, and `beginPath` discards it. If you want an old path back, you'll have to call `beginPath` to discard your current one and then reconstruct your old one from the individual instructions. (I don't quite understand what you mean by “an index type situation”.)

Answer (score 9):

`beginPath()` clears the old path so you can define a new one.

`closePath()` connects the first point with the last point and is not needed in your example. In any case it would have be used before stroking of filling to have an effect on the rasterized result.

Comment: Is there a way to recall paths that have been used before. Can you have five beginPath() and five closePath() in a canvas and recall the second path.

Comment: There will be in the future where you can use individual Path objects. However, there is no browsers which implements this fully yet. You would for now need to recreate the paths one at the time.

Comment: There will be benefit to use the path objects so it is a good idea to use them like there would be a reason.