# Display and Draw in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've been trying to display shapes (coordinates are generated in js) and can draw freely in my canvas.

If I tried joining to use the same canvas to be displayed, big mess happens:

here's my code:

```js
function display() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(document.getElementById('color1').checked){
      context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    } else if(document.getElementById('color2').checked){
      context.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
           
           context.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
           
           context.stroke();
                }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
            
            context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);
            
            context.stroke();
                }
   }


    $(function () {
        $('#displaycake_sketch').sketch();
        $(".tools a").eq(0).attr("style", "color:#fba557");
        $(".tools a").click(function () {
            $(".tools a").removeAttr("style");
            $(this).attr("style", "color:#000");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

   
<canvas id="displaycake_sketch"></canvas>
<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design" value="RED" onchange="display()"/> RED  
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design" value="BLUE" onchange="display()"/> BLUE </div>

<div class="tools"> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="marker"> Marker</a> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="eraser"> Eraser</a>

</div>
```

As you can see, whenever I tried to draw, the shapes disappears. and when I choose again some in my options, the lines will be disappear.. My eraser is working only for the marker.

And when I tried using different canvas, you can't draw freely but only the shapes can be displayed (I used position:absolute; to stay the same place)

Hope somebody can help, thank you so much!!

Comment: You need to take this back to the drawing board... lol, sorry, couldn't resist. Seriously though, you need to look at a canvas cheat sheet, mostly about when `beginPath()` is actually needed, and the fact that the path needs to be closed before it can be used.

Comment: sorry my code was a mess, so I just need to remove those `beginPath()' ?

Comment: No, you need to look at the actual docs. You need to begin and close the path for lines, arcs and curves. You don't need one for rectangles or circles, afaik. http://cheatsheetworld.com/programming/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @ChrisG I've update my code here and there were some changes that I've almost wanted. I removed the `beginpath` since I already generated the shapes, thank you. If you try to run my code now the lines shows up already everytime I doodle around but disappears 3-5 secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
https://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js
```

It's not a random 3-5 seconds, but some event is firing as a result of your interaction with the canvas element:

```
  this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
```

You'll need to hijack the redraw method and chain your own code to it, for example, one quick and dirty option is to:

```
$(function() {
  var drawObject = $('#displaycake_sketch').sketch();
  var oldRedraw = drawObject.data('sketch').redraw;
  drawObject.data('sketch').redraw = function () {
    oldRedraw.call(this);
    display();
  }
  $(".tools a").eq(0).attr("style", "color:#fba557");
  $(".tools a").click(function() {
    $(".tools a").removeAttr("style");
    $(this).attr("style", "color:#000");
  });
});
```

You also want to do a
  context.beginPath();
when doing your display function, so that the doodled path ends and a new shape starts. (And not clear the canvas so the doodled path stays).

Final code is:

```js
  function display() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();

    if (document.getElementById('color1').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    } else if (document.getElementById('color2').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {

      context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

      context.stroke();
    }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {

      context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);

      context.stroke();
    }
  }


  $(function() {
    var drawObject = $('#displaycake_sketch').sketch();
    var oldRedraw = drawObject.data('sketch').redraw;
    window.redraw = drawObject.data('sketch').redraw = function() {
      oldRedraw.call(this);
      display();
    }
    window.redraw = function () {
      drawObject.data('sketch').redraw();
    }
    $(".tools a").eq(0).attr("style", "color:#fba557");
    $(".tools a").click(function() {
      $(".tools a").removeAttr("style");
      $(this).attr("style", "color:#000");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

   
<canvas id="displaycake_sketch"></canvas>
<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="redraw()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="redraw()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design" value="RED" onchange="display()"/> RED  
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design" value="BLUE" onchange="display()"/> BLUE </div>

<div class="tools"> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="marker"> Marker</a> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="eraser"> Eraser</a>

</div>
```

**UPDATE to show circle or square when clicking radio buttons**
The existing "display" function doesn't clear the canvas (or redraw the sketched path). To ensure a redraw, where the old radio selection is erased and only the new radio selection is drawn, we need to call the sketch-redraw function then our "display" fn. A quick and dirty way is to wrap the sketch fn, which has sketch and display both being called, into a global function the onclick radio button event can call. Code updated above.

Regarding close path, this is a good overview: [Do I have to have the content.beginPath() and content.closePath()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432036/do-i-have-to-have-the-content-beginpath-and-content-closepath)

Comment: WOW!, thank you so much! I'm really having a hard time to understand the codes in the sketch.js , How do I fix the bug in my Radio button? When I choose circle, only circle will appear same with rectangle. The color is working well..

Comment: , is the closepath neccessary in here?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that the rectangle and circle both stay?

Comment: no, I wanted to display one shape only at a time. if i choose circle, only circle will appear. If rectangle, only rectangle will appear.